# Bounding box and groups in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, bounding-box

In the past I have been able to group objects and use the bounding box to center my selections. I checked "hide bounding box" and it is not active. I've also checked "hide edges"

I also can't rotate my selections anymore using this method.

It also seems like even though I have it "grouped" and am using the new group selection tool, it doesn't allow me to transform the entire selection.

What is happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using the *Group Selection Tool* (Which  is just a way of selecting multiple objects - like pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>*)

Switch to the (regular) *Selection Tool* <kbd>V</kbd> and then you should see it.

By holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> you are temporarily switching to the Selection Tool

---

You may also have disabled the bounding box.

Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to toggle the *Bounding Box* **ON / OFF**

You can also go to **View → Show/Hide Bounding Box**

---

<sub>*That is my understanding of that tool, not 100% sure.</sub>

Comment: I found that if I hit CTRL while my selection is active I can see my box. The View>Show/Hide method didn't work. So weird. I'll do some more research on the new group selection tool. I can't imagine why the developers would change this function.

Comment: BINGO!!!! Thank you Welz. I hope this helps others. I've been sitting here scratching my head.